# Received : Invalid URI : The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: c#, web, uri, invalidation

So i'm using this to load a site 
:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string str2 = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            if (Program.proxies.Count > 0)
            {
                string Address = Program.proxies[new Random().Next(0, Program.proxies.Count)];
                string[] strArray = Address.Split(':');
                if (strArray.Length > 2)
                    webClient.Proxy = (IWebProxy)new WebProxy(strArray[0] + ":" + strArray[1])
                    {
                        Credentials = (ICredentials)new NetworkCredential(strArray[2], strArray[3])
                    };
                else
                    webClient.Proxy = (IWebProxy)new WebProxy(Address);
            }
            return str2.Replace("&#39;", "'");
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText("log.txt"))
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + ex1.Message);
                str1 = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                str1 = "";
            }
        }
```

and i get Invalid URI : The hostname could not be parsed in the log , used to work, and i added a windows form and now i can't make it work like it used to... and like a dumb... i deleted my old project

Comment: What is `Program.proxies`? What is `url`?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was my proxy list file that had a space in it

Comment: If you find the answer mark this as the answer of the question so that other people may have this problem have the answer.